# UINavigationItem of ChildviewController

Tags: ios, inheritance, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

[image]I have Base Controller and Child View Controllers. I want to create `UINvaigationItem` in Base Controller in storyboard, to make Child controllers inherit it, and show. I create this `UINavigationItem` in `storyboard` for Base Controller. Child Controllers not showing this `UINavigationItem` from Base controller, and it's properties are all nil. How can i make `UINavigationItem` from BaseController be in ChildViewControllers?

This is picture of storyboard, on the left is Base Controller, on the right is Child ViewControllers.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your Q, are you asking how to accomplish this?

Comment: yes, if you have some ideas, it would be great

Comment: Please include your code if you have anything, and try to rephrase the question to be more understandable.

Comment: There almost no code at all,i will rephrase. I have Base Controller and Child View Controllers. I want to create UINvaigationItem in Base Controller in storyboard, to make Child controllers inherit it, and show. I create this UINavigationItem in storyboard for Base Controller. Child Controllers not showing this UINavigationItem from BASE controller, and it's properties are all nil. How can i make UINavigationItem from BaseController be in ChildViewControllers?

Comment: Have someone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't un-inherit the UINavigation in ChildViewController because it is part of the views stack in the UINavigation, but you can call

```
// hide navigation bar
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

This will hide the navigation bar on the ChildViewController

You can use the `pop` methods in the ChildViewController to programmatically control the navigation stack

**EDIT**

Base on your photo i see you haven't connected all the `ViewControlleres` in the storyBoard to the navigationViewController.

I recommend not creating the UIViewController like you did.
1) simply add & connect the view controllers you wish to be in the navigation stack

2) select them and in Xcode menu go to Editor->Embed in-> Navigation Controller

That way, all the views will be included in the navigation stack and have a reference to the UINavigationViewController

Comment: on what question this answer is? Please, read my last comment.

Comment: how did you created the navigation Bar? dragged from the assets library? or did you embedded it?

Comment: I didn't create NavigationBar,Navigation bar is created through UINavigationController. I create UINavigationItem for Base controller for child to use it.

Comment: can u add a photo of your storyboard?

Comment: i added photo of storyboard

Comment: Man, i don't need a reference to navigation controller.I just need child controllers inherit uinavigationItem of base controller, that is implemented in storyboard. If they inherit that property, next time i would show child controller, navigation controller will take uinavigationitem and display navigation bar correctly. How to make it inherit this property?

Comment: I don't need navigationBar to be shown in storyboard, i just need child controller to inherit base controller UINavigationItem property, and show it in runtime, when i push it to navigation controller stack